# Ordenación de todos los datos en un dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Dispongo de un df de 4 filas y 20 columnas.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   75  28  74  76  38  82  28  90  51  54  64  61  48  70  59  52  84  45  60  30
1   49  54  87  18  66  63  56  23  59  100 69  59  24  33  61  15  29  33  75  74
2   45  66  41  51  87  49  63  41  51  35  95  53  40  22  29  76  34  19  48  75
3   60  69  73  75  60  56  52  74  88  38  66  30  49  56  45  59  79  61  67  27
```

Deseo crear otro dataframe con "todos" los datos ordenados en orden ascendente.
He seguido el siguiente proceso.
Ordeno todos los datos utilizando numpy, con lo que obtengo una lista con los datos ordenados en el orden requerido.

```
# Ordenación de los datos.
import numpy as np
datos = np.sort(tabla, axis=None)
```

Partiendo de dicha lista he creado un array de 4 x 20 y lo convertido en df.

```
# Create ndArray from a list
array_datos_ordenados = np.array(datos.reshape(4,20))
df_datos_ordenados = pd.DataFrame(array_datos_ordenados)
```

Mi duda es si hay alguna forma más sencilla y lógica de realizar este ordenamiento con pandas, sin recurrir a numpy.

Comment: Ummm que yo sepa no hay una forma directa de hacerlo, pandas tiene múltiples formas de ordenar columnas y filas en función de múltiples condiciones pero en este caso desestructuras todo el DataFrame mezclando datos de distintas columnas, si las columnas fueran de distinto tipo (algo muy común en Pandas) sería un problema el ordenamiento... No hay nada malo en usar NumPy, pandas está cimentado en NumPy.  La construcción del último array no es necesaria, basta con `df_datos_ordenados = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(tabla, axis=None).reshape(tabla.shape))`